# Is it possible to use a custom object instead of String inside a Tkinter Text Widget (python)?

Tags: python, string, user-interface, tkinter, subclass

I'm trying to create a text editor that will manipulate a string like object.  Ideally I would like to subclass Tkinter's Text Widget or some other Gui module to allow me to substitute this custom object instead of using strings.

I understand how to create the object itself (which essentially just tags every word with meta-data), but not how to manipulate the rendered object as text while retaining its other attributes.

Eg.
The text editor imports a file that contains "Hello World".  Upon opening this text, both words are tag'd with relevant attributes.  (Displayed below as a dictionary, but ideally an object Hello.strContent, Hello.index, etc.)

```
Hello={strContent: "Hello", index: 0, speaker: "Joe", paragraph: 3}
World={strContent: "World", index: 1, speaker: "Joe", paragraph: 3}
```

Now I'm completely stumped though how I could make these string like objects manipulable, and subject to cutting, copying, pasting, deleting, and rearranging, inside a Text gui.  I would not need to have the program allow me to type any new words or create new objects, just manipulate the objects that have been initialized upon converting the file I opened.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you couldn't just add the `strContent` to the text as a string or even refer to each object from a dictionary? As in, each word is a dictionary key where the value assigned to that key is the dictionary you have outlined above?

Comment: I like the idea of utilizing a dictionary, but the source text will contain duplicates of the same words.  For example, an ugly solution would render the text with an index appended to the start of each word.<br>

00And 01here 02is 03a 04sample 05text 06which 07is 08simple.<br>

Now, say I edit this text in our hypothetical Gui editor to read:<br>

Comment: Could you create a list then? Append each object to a list in order as you read them in, then iterate through the list and add each `strContent` to the `text` widget?

Comment: Now, say I edit this text in our hypothetical Gui editor to read: 05text 07is 01here.  Now, I can use a separate indexed list to cross reference these index values.  However, I want the text to be nice and readable, so this solution doesn't work.

Comment: If I create a list and add strContent to the text widget, how could I rearrange that text in the text widget and have it retain each words metadata?  I guess I'm wondering how the strContent in the text widget, remains linked to its metadata, because now it's been reduced from a myObj to a str.

Comment: I mean, the first solutiont which jumps to mind if you absolutely need to edit the text in the `text` widget is prepend with a certain combination of invisible characters to represent an index, but that sounds terrible. I'm sure there's another way to do it. But I don't believe that `text` widget's can have anything other than strings in them. Why do you need to have them be custom objects?

Comment: The more I think about this it seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), maybe we can find another way of achieving what you want if you tell us why they're dictionaries?

Comment: They don't have to be dictionaries.  I just wanted represent an idea of the data.  Ideally they would be objects.  And all those dictionary items, would be attributes.

Comment: I mean, you are declaring them as dictionaries in your code. `{"foo": "bar"}` is called a dictionary in Python. What I want to know is **why** they **need** to have these attributes associated with them?

Comment: Got it.  I have a video, and a transcript created from that video.  I want to edit the transcript, but have it maintain a link to the timing of the video. The indexes which are mentioned here, would actually be timecode, so that the new transcript that has been edited in our text editor could be reconstituted through an EDL or FCP XML into a video.

Comment: I don't understand what any of that has to do with putting an object into a `text` widget?

Comment: Do you want all of this metadata to actually be visible within the text (in which case, format it however you want, and parse it out of the text afterwards), or merely be associated with pieces of the text even after editing (which I'm not sure is possible - in particular, cut/paste of text isn't going to preserve anything but the visible text)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: this attempts to answer the question that was asked, but I suspect this is an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). At the end of this answer I'll give some other suggestions.

---

The text widget can't have some complex object as its underlying data structure. It can display text, and it can have tags associated with the text. You can also insert images and widgets, but I think that's irrelevant to what you are asking.

When reading the data in, you can construct tags for each piece of metadata, and associate those tags with a range of text. For example, the word "Hello" could have the tags "paragraph:3", "speaker:Joe", and "index:0". "World" would be similar, except it would have the tag "index:1".

This would be easy to do when initially displaying the data. For example:

```
data = [{"strContent": "Hello", "index": 0, "speaker": "Joe", "paragraph": 3},
        {"strContent": "World", "index": 1, "speaker": "Joe", "paragraph": 3}
]

for item in data:
    tags = (
        "index:%d" % item['index'],
        "speaker:%s" % item['speaker'],
        "paragraph:%d" % item['paragraph']
    )
    self.text.insert("end", item['strContent'], tags)
```

If you then go in and insert "r" in the word "World", it will inherit the tags of the surrounding text.

You can get the data back out of the widget with the `dump` method, which returns a stream of data. For example, `self.text.dump("1.0", "end-1c", tag=True, text=True, mark=False)` yields this information:

```
[
 ('tagon', 'paragraph:3', '1.0'), 
 ('tagon', 'speaker:Joe', '1.0'), 
 ('tagon', 'index:0', '1.0'), 
 ('text', 'Hello', '1.0'), 
 ('tagoff', 'index:0', '1.5'), 
 ('tagon', 'index:1', '1.5'), 
 ('text', 'World', '1.5')
]
```

Reassembling that data back to your original format is tricky. Here's a rough cut of an attempt, though I don't know how it would stand up in the real world. It might be possible for users to edit the data in ways that totally mess up the structure.

```
def get_data(self):
    result = []
    meta = {}
    for item in self.text.dump("1.0", "end-1c", tag=True, text=True, mark=False):
        if item[0] == "tagon":
            (name, value) = item[1].split(":")
            meta[name] = value

        if item[0] == "tagoff":
            (name, value) = item[1].split(":")
            del meta[name]

        if item[0] == "text":
            text = item[1]
            # if this text has the same tags as the previous text,
            # don't create a new item; instead, append the text to
            # the previous item
            if result and all(item in result[-1].items() for item in meta.items()):
                result[-1]["strContent"] += text
            else:
                data = {"strContent": text}
                data.update(meta)
                result.append(data)

    return result
```

---

Not knowing what you're actually trying to accomplish, a text widget might not be the best solution since it gives the user a bit too much freedom to alter the text. For example, what should happen if they change "Hello" to "HelloWorld", and then delete the original "World"? Do they end up with one "HelloWorld" item, or the original two "Hello" and "World" items?

You might want to consider using either a canvas, where each text item is a distinct object (which can also have tags), or perhaps you might want to use a series of entry widgets so that the data in once can't bleed over into the other.

Comment: Thanks Bryan.  Ideally, each word should maintain itself as a distinct object, and the text should not be mutable.  The word should only be subject to the operations: insert (reposition), delete, or copy (and insert). The canvas widget seems like a great suggestion, but I'm worried about ease of use to perform the above operations.  The use case would involve multipage transcripts, that I would want to edit, with each word maintaining it's tags.  I'll try to implement what you've mentioned.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

i think that you could do something like

```
class myobj:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.strContent=text
hello = [[myobj("Hello"), myObj("World")], [myobj("Paragraph"), myobj("2")]]
```

then whenever you need to display that text, you would have it loop through like so

```
printableStr = ""
for paragraph in hello:
    for word in paragraph:
        printableStr += word.strContent + " "
    printableStr += "\n"
```

and then printableStr will be a nice string containing all info from hello

Comment: This definitely works to display the text, but I am looking to manipulate the text after it's been displayed, and have each word still retain it's metadata.  Ideally it would be manipulated in a text editor like app, but that manipulates myObjs instead of strings.